# Column cannot be null Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

I have 2 tables in relation, where id_pengguna is foreign key for table pengguna.

Table pengguna:

- id (int) (AI)
- nama_unit
- pengguna

Table pertanyaan:

- id (AI)
- pertanyaan
- id_pengguna (int) (FK)

Model:

```
public function savePertanyaan($data){
        return $this->db->table('pertanyaan')->insert($data);
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function save()
    {
        
        $data = array(
            'pertanyaan'     => $this->request->getVar('pertanyaan'),
            'id_pengguna'   => $this->request->getVar('id_pengguna')
        );

        $this->pertModel->savePertanyaan($data);
        return redirect()->to(base_url('SAdmin/pertSurvei'));
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group row">
 <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Pertanyaan</label>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pertanyaan" placeholder="Input Question">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Unit</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <select name="id_unit" class="form-control">
        <option value="">-Pilih-</option>
        <?php foreach($pengguna as $key => $value):?>
        <option value="<?= $value['id'];?>"><?= $value['nama_unit'];?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
       </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

the error is Column 'id_pengguna' cannot be null, i still can't find where the problem is. I hope you can help me to find it. Thanks

Comment: Post your full view `form`,

Comment: Thank you, im already found the error. yes its from the view. i put a wrong name in select name. thanks before

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer

Answer (score 1):

### Change View

You does not assign `id_pengguna` as a value in your `name` attribute. But you called `id_pengguna` from your `Controller` by `$this->request->getVar('id_pengguna')`.

You need to change the `name` attribute value from `id_unit` to `id_pengguna`.

**From**

```
<select name="id_unit" class="form-control">
```

**To**

```
<select name="id_pengguna" class="form-control">
```

**After changing your `view` part:**

```
<div class="form-group row">
 <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Pertanyaan</label>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pertanyaan" placeholder="Input Question">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Unit</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <select name="id_pengguna" class="form-control">
        <option value="">-Pilih-</option>
        <?php foreach($pengguna as $key => $value):?>
        <option value="<?= $value['id'];?>"><?= $value['nama_unit'];?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
       </select>
     </div>
</div>
```